# EF: saving data to view in DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, entity-framework

I have two tables in the DB,

I have used a `view` in order to map them into one object in my application (using EF)

howw can I perform `save()` to this view?

will `EfContect.SaveChanges();` be enough?

Or should I get both relevant items (2 tables)

modify them according to the view's change and then apply `EfContect.SaveChanges();` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Making an Updateable View Accept Updates in ADO.NET Entities Framework](http://www.bitsinsight.com/making-an-updateable-view-accept-updates-in-ado-net-entities-framework/):

> - Change store:Type=”Views” to store:Type=”Tables”
> - Remove store: prefix from the Schema property
> - Remove the store:Name attribute
> - Comment out the  element

Comment: I don't understand this line:
`if you generate a view with VIEW_METADATA and add instead of triggers for insert/update/delete.` How do I know if my view is editable? do I have to write `sp` to each CRUD opertaion?

Comment: It depends which DB engine you use. Here is about views in `SQL Server`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx (`Updatable Views` paragraph)